workflow_run determines wrong gitversion
So I recently started making the switch from DevOps to GitHub for our repositories and CI/CD.
But I'm running into some issues, and I'm not sure how to fix it.
We have a "build" workflow
name: build

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop 
      - release/*
      - main
      - hotfix/*

*snip*

This step will do the building of the project and (if needed) run the tests on both any pull requests, or a push to the protected branches. (We're using GitFlow as a branching strategy)
Then I have another workflow file which triggers on the completion of the build workflow for specific (the protected) branches:
name: deployment

on:
  workflow_run: 
    workflows: 
      - build
    types: 
      - completed
    branches: 
      - develop 
      - release/*
      - main
      - hotfix/*

jobs:        
  determineVersion:
  # Determine the version for tag & packages
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs: 
      Version: ${{ steps.determination.outputs.Version }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
      - name: Install GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v3.0.0
        with:
          versionSpec: '6.x'
      - name: Execute GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v3.0.0
        id: gitversion
      # Determine the version, for main releases we don't want the SemVer, but the MajorMinorPatch
      - name: Determine version
        id: determination
        run: |
          if [[ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/heads/main" ]]; then
          echo "Version=${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.MajorMinorPatch }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          else
          echo "Version=${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.SemVer }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          fi

*snip*

In here, we want to:

Use GitVersion to determine the next version
Create a tag
Publish any NuGet packages to our private feed
Deploy the application

Everything works as expected for pull requests and develop branch, untill I create a "release/*" branch. GitVersion wants to create an alpha tag, which isn't correct, it should be a beta tag.
The output from the gitversion execute:
Writing version variables to $GITHUB_ENV file for 'GitHubActions'.
{
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "1.1.0.0",
  "AssemblySemVer": "1.1.0.0",
  "BranchName": "develop",
  "BuildMetaData": null,
  "CommitDate": "2024-11-08",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 0,
  "EscapedBranchName": "develop",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "Branch.develop.Sha.686f582b550e63f06be4999be5ec5d7f4efacced",
  "FullSemVer": "1.1.0-alpha.0",
  "InformationalVersion": "1.1.0-alpha.0+Branch.develop.Sha.686f582b550e63f06be4999be5ec5d7f4efacced",
  "Major": 1,
  "MajorMinorPatch": "1.1.0",
  "Minor": 1,
  "Patch": 0,
  "PreReleaseLabel": "alpha",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "-alpha",
  "PreReleaseNumber": 0,
  "PreReleaseTag": "alpha.0",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "-alpha.0",
  "SemVer": "1.1.0-alpha.0",
  "Sha": "686f582b550e63f06be4999be5ec5d7f4efacced",
  "ShortSha": "686f582",
  "UncommittedChanges": 0,
  "VersionSourceSha": "686f582b550e63f06be4999be5ec5d7f4efacced",
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 0
}

as you can see, it says the branch name is develop, while I'm checking out the branch that triggered the workflow_run (in this case release/1.0.0)
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
